# React Native App runs only through the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I start my app through `expo start` in the terminal, the QR code doesn't generate. And when I launch it through the Expo app on my phone

the result is that the project is online but it has a different thumbnail and launches through the browser:

[image: project is online]

If I try and change the url of it from `http://192.168.1.94:19006` to `exp://192.168.1.94:19006` like the rest of my apps, it shows

[image: error-1]

and after clicking the view error log at the bottom, it returns

[image: error-2]:

```
Uncaught Error: java.io.IOException: Manifest string is not a valid JSONObject or JSONArray: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> This viewport works for phones with notches. It's optimized for gesture
```

How do I make it run normally on my phone through the expo app instead of through the browser?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I suddenly just started getting this error and I didn't really do any big changes from it working to not working.

Comment: Seems it's cause by expo-dev-client. I don't know why it causes it when it is installed. Removed it and the app now runs properly on expo go on android.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in my experience, an issue not relating to your code, but the settings on your phone or the network itself.

Here's a few steps I recommend:

1. Make sure wireless debugging is turned on. My OnePlus phone often
   turns off wireless debugging when I switch networks.
2. Switch to tunnel, there are often funny issues on Public Networks.
3. Go to settings on your phone and find expo's settings. Turn the setting
   "Display over other apps", to off then on again (it should
   definitely be on).
4. Uninstall Expo Dev clients AND builds, this is often the cause for me.
5. Try a wired connection (make sure USB debugging is on).
6. Reinstall Expo Go on your phone

This can be a real pain, good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the terminal where you're running Expo is what worked on my end :)

Answer (score -2):

Check you app.json, list your OS's in platforms

```
"expo": {
  "name": "",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android",
    "web"
  ],
  ...
}
```